# Shipping calculator locks up half the time

Tags: magento2, shipping

I am currently running Magento 2.3.1 and about half the time I am using the shipping calculator at checkout, it locks up the option to choose which service to ship. If I re-enter the zip code or refresh the page a few times, it will eventually start working again. Is this a common issue? Any ways to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is known bug in magento2 for fix override

> Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service.js

in your custom theme and add below code

```
jQuery(".table-checkout-shipping-method input[type=radio]").prop("disabled", false);
```

at the end of the setShippingRates(rates) function

check below link for reference.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7497

Comment: Thanks for the info! I tried the fix you mentioned and it did not work for me on v2.3.1. But I read through the thread you sent me and this fixed the issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7497#issuecomment-280779055